# Three.js OBJ loader Raycaster get Parent

Tags: javascript, object, three.js

im currently building a smal 3d configurator. I stumbled upon the problem, that if I use the Raycaster to trigger an event, I have to enable recursive when using .intersectObject(). But I need to change the position of the 'parent' if you might call it that way. Is it possible to refer to the object loaded with the obj loader instead of the descendant?

Here is my mouseDown function:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ){
event.preventDefault();

raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( ObjectArr, true );

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

    SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;

    if ( raycaster.ray.intersectPlane( plane, intersection ) ) {

        console.log("Plane Intersection");
        SELECTED.doSomething...

    }

}

}
```

So SELECTED is not a value of ObjectArr. I need to refer to the position from another function. Is there a possibility to refer to the parent object?

Comment: have you tried SELECTED.parent ? http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D

Comment: If Derte's answer doesn't help, then maybe don't use `true` in intersectObjects because that will include any object children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Derte Trdelnik.

The solution was to use SELECTED.parent.